# sencha touch: cant remove record from session storage

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, session-storage

Cant delete a record from the store.

My model

```
Ext.define('touch.model.FilesModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'
],
config: {
    identifier: 'uuid',
    idProperty: 'iD',
    fields: [
        { name: 'iD', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'fileName', type: 'auto' }
    ]
}
});
```

and this is my SessionStorage

```
Ext.define('touch.store.FilesStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.proxy.SessionStorage'
],
config: {
    storeId: 'FilesStore',
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'touch.model.FilesModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'sessionstorage',
        id: 'FilesStore-store-unique'
    },
    sorters: [{
        property: 'created',
        direction: 'DESC'
    }]
}
});
```

I am trying to remove a record from the store, and it doesnt work. 
i tried:

```
var filesStore = Ext.getStore('FilesStore');
    filesStore.remove(filesStore.getAt(index)); // fails on this line: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null"  remove from the store
    filesStore.sync();
```

then i tried just to do

```
var filesStore = Ext.getStore('FilesStore');
    filesStore.getAt(index).erase() // fails with: [ERROR][Anonymous] You are trying to erase a model instance that doesn't have a Proxy specified
```

Comment: my ugly workaround is:
1. put records i want to keep to the array (var arrayOfRecordsToKeep=[]).
2. remove all records from the store: store.removeAll() -> that function works
3. add records back: store.add(arrayOfRecordsToKeep)

Comment: is your store have data at same index? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null" this error show your model instance is null.

Comment: yeah, it does. filesStore.getAt(index) returns existing object

Comment: remove your store id..you can get your store using store file name and try..